# Fiddler not capturing traffic from .Net Core

Tags: c#, https, .net-core, fiddler

I have a console app that calls a number of 3rd party services via HTTP/HTTPS that was originally written to run under the .Net Framework. Fiddler works fine with that version of the app, capturing all of the HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

I ported the app to .net Core 2.1 and now Fiddler does not capture any of the HTTP/HTTPS traffic from the app.

Any suggestions as to why Fiddler (v5.0) is not working to capture traffic from the .Net Core app?

Answer (score 16):

In my office environment, Fiddler still does not intercept requests that are issued by .NET Core 2.2 against external resources. I guess this is due to our local proxy setup.

My workaround is to capture requests from .NET Core 2.2 by explicitly defining Fiddler as a proxy to be used by the HttpClient class:

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(
           handler: new HttpClientHandler
           {
               // 8888 = Fiddler standard port
               Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://localhost:8888")),  
               UseProxy = true
           }
        );
```

This reliably tunnels all requests coming from Core through Fiddler.

Comment: @Mahesh: Whereever you use a HttpClient to access online resources, you can instantiate it with this code. It will then use Fiddler as a proxy for all its requests. For this to work Fiddler MUST be running as a proxy. Otherwise the requests will not get answered and will time out.

Answer (score 7):

In .NET Core 2.1 the default provider was changed from WinHttpHandler to the new SocketsHttpHandler, built entirely on the .NET networking stack.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28603 indicates that Fiddler is expected to work, so verify that you have the latest update for 2.1 and, if things continue not to work, report an issue to corefx on github.

Answer (score 5):

Small addition. In case of using [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) with DI the proxy can be set this way

```
services.AddHttpClient<ISomeService, SomeService>()
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://localhost:8888")),
        UseProxy = true
    });
```